# Error : Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I'm getting **'Null check operator used on a null value'** on my user profile page.

User Account Code

```
/*
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';*/
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'login.dart';

class UserAcc extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserAcc({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UserAcc> createState() => _UserAccState();
}

class _UserAccState extends State<UserAcc> {
  String? name;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  **final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;**

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyLogin()));
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            child: Card(
                elevation: 30.0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0)),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        ),
                        Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded, color: Colors.black38, size: 40,),
                        Text(
                          " User Details",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black38,
                              letterSpacing: 2.0,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      **" Name : " + user.displayName!,**
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black38,
                          letterSpacing: 2.0,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      **" Email : " + user.displayName!,**
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black38,
                          letterSpacing: 2.0,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                        signOut();
                      },
                      child: Text("Sign out"),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.pink,
                          fixedSize: const Size(100, 30),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50))),
                    ),
                  ],

                ),

            ),


        ),

      ),


    );

  }
}
```

Error Log

> The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
> Null check operator used on a null value
> The relevant error-causing widget was: MaterialApp
> MaterialApp:file:///C:/Users/Debangi%20Bhaumik/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/android/app/lib/**main.dart**:21:12

Hence it says the error is in main.dart, i'm attaching the main.dart file

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'signup.dart';
import 'startuppage.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());

}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: 'login', // It will direct route to login page
      routes: {
        'login': (context) => const MyLogin(),
        'signup': (context) => const Mysignup(),
      },
    );



  }
}
```

**Mylogin() page :**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'startuppage.dart';

class MyLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyLogin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyLogin> createState() => _MyLoginState();
}

class _MyLoginState extends State<MyLogin> {


  //editing controller
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  int _success = 1 ;
  late String _userEmail = "";

  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;


  Future SignIn() async {

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text.trim(),
        password: passwordController.text.trim()
    );

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return  Container(
      decoration:  const BoxDecoration(
        //color: Color(0xFFaac8ba),
        gradient: LinearGradient
          (begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: [
          Color(0xFFde6262),
            Color(0xFFffb88c)
          ]
        ),
      ),
      child : Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, //By default, in scaffold the bg color is white.

        body: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 130, left: 35, right: 0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children:  [
                    const  Text(
                      "Welcome Back\nTo Check-it.",
                      style:  TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        letterSpacing: 3,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),

                    const  SizedBox(
                      height: 50.0,
                    ),
                   TextField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration:  const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Email",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail, color: Colors.black,)
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                     TextField(
                       controller:passwordController,
                      obscureText: true,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                      decoration:  const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Password",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.black,)
                      ),
                    ),
                    const  SizedBox(
                      height: 50.0,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async{
                       // _signIn();
                        SignIn();
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Imageslider()),
                        );
                      },
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black12),
                      ),
                      child: const Text("Login",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Text(
                          _success == 1
                              ?''
                              : (
                              _success == 2
                                  ? 'Sign-in successful! '
                                  : 'Sign-in failed!'),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                          )
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children:  [
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context,'signup');
                            },
                            child: const Text ('New User? Sign Up',
                              style : TextStyle(
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Colors.black45,
                              ),
                            )),


                      ],

                    ),


                  ],

                ),
              ),
            ),
        ),
      );


  }
}
```

**My Signup Code :**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import 'startuppage.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class Mysignup extends StatefulWidget {
  const Mysignup({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Mysignup> createState() => _MysignupState();
}

class _MysignupState extends State<Mysignup> {

  Future<FirebaseApp> _initializeFirebase() async {
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp();
    return firebaseApp;
  }

  //editing controller
  final TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  late bool _success;
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future<User?> _register(String name, String email, String password) async{
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    try {
      UserCredential userCrendetial =  await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);

      print("Account created Succesfull");

      userCrendetial.user?.updateDisplayName(name);


      await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser?.uid).set({
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "uid": _auth.currentUser?.uid,
      });

      return userCrendetial.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration:  const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient
          (colors: [
          Color(0xFF02aab0),
          Color(0xFF00cdac)
        ],
        ),
      ),
      child : Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, //By default, in scaffold the bg color is white.

        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150, left: 35, right: 35),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children:  [
                const Text(
                  "Let's Create Together.",
                  style:  TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    letterSpacing: 3,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 40.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller:name,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                  decoration:  const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Name",
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded, color: Colors.black,)
                  ),
                ),

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller:emailController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration:  const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Email",
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail, color: Colors.black,)
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller:passwordController,
                  obscureText: true,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                  decoration:  const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Password",
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.black,)
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 80.0,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async{
                    if (name.text.isNotEmpty &&
                        emailController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                        passwordController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                      setState(() {
                        isLoading = true;
                      });

                     _register(name.text, emailController.text, passwordController.text).then((user) {
                        if (user == null) {
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = false;
                          });
                          Navigator.push(
                              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Imageslider()));
                          print("Account Created Sucessful");
                        } else {
                          print("Login Failed");
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = false;
                          });
                        }
                      });
                    } else {

                      print("Please enter all the fields");
                    }
                  },
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black12),
                  ),
                  child: const Text("Sign Up",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );


  }
}
```

***Stracktrace***

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following _CastError was thrown building Builder: Null check operator used on a null value
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    MaterialApp
> MaterialApp:file:///C:/Users/Debangi%20Bhaumik/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/android/app/lib/main.dart:21:12
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      new _UserAccState (file:///C:/Users/Debangi%20Bhaumik/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/android/app/lib/useracc.dart:22:49)
> #1      UserAcc.createState (file:///C:/Users/Debangi%20Bhaumik/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/android/app/lib/useracc.dart:16:35)
> #2      new StatefulElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4891:25)
> #3      StatefulWidget.createElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:758:38) ...     Normal
> element mounting (275 frames)
> #278    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:16)
> #279    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6350:36)
> #280    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
> #281    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5883:32)
> #282    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
> #283    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
> #284    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
> #285    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
> #286    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
> #287    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
> #288    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
> #289    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
> #290    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
> #291    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
> #292    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
> #293    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
> #294    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
> #295    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
> #296    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:108:11)
> #297    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
> #298    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
> #299    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
> #300    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
> #301    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
> #302    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
> #303    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
> #304    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
> #305    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
> #306    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
> #307    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
> #308    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
> #309    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
> #310    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
> #311    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
> #312    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
> #313    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
> #314    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
> #315    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
> #316    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
> #317    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:891:21)
> #318    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
> #319    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
> #320    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
> #321    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:997:5)
> #325    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
> #326    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
> #327    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31) (elided 3 frames from dart:async)

I'm a beginner at this, please help me. I'm stuck at this stage for days.Thank you in advance1

Comment: Does the stacktrace contain more lines? Also you did not include the MyLogin/Mysignup pages.

Comment: Sorry, I will add them right now.

Comment: You have lines in your code that do this: '''final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; **final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;**'''. First, why are you not using the _auth variable? Second are you sure currentUser exists?

Comment: Cause i'm new to this and I was following a video. I have tried to remove "!" from  '''final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;'''

Comment: Regarding if i'm sure if the currentUser exists, it was fetch the current user values, like email and displayname

Comment: The error you have states that a null check operator (!) was used on a null value. Therefore, it could possibly be that accessing the currentUser field is problematic since it is null. And even if you are following a video tutorial, it would be best to look at what you are writing and understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the complete stacktrace and the error, it is pretty clear that you are using a null check operator (the exclamation mark -> !) on a null value.

If you look at the [documentation for Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users), you can see that they access the currentUser by doing this:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
   print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid);
}
```

Whereas, you are doing this:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; 
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```